# Shortcut to change screen scale

Tags: 20.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, display

Is there a way to easily change the scale percentage (between 100% and 200%) with a shortcut on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome?
I use my computer both with a regular screen which doesn't need scaling and a 4K projector which requires a scale of 200% for me to see what I'm doing.

I know there is the screen parameter where I can change the scale, but I want a faster way to do it.